# Why is du -sh faster after running ncdu?

Tags: linux

I have large (400 GB+) directories containing source code. I have noticed that `du -sh directory` takes up to 30 min. However ncdu is  faster and take around 2 min. When I run `du -sh` after the ncdu invocation, it is way faster and completes in under 2 min. Successive `du` commands are as fast. I was wondering why running ncdu speeds up du. Is there some kind of caching involved?

Answer (score 3):

`du`  command does not have a cache mechanism.

Instead when you do run `du` command, It uses `stat()` to calculate the disk usage of a directory based on the inode size of each file on it and then make a summary of them.

Knowing that `stat()` metadata are cached by the OS, this will reduce `du` or `ncdu` execution time during multiple and successive runs.

Comment: In this case successive `du`s after the first slow one would also be faster